# Laravel Eloquent pagination on relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to paginate a Eloquent relationship like this:

```
 $query = Product::find(1)->options()->paginate();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCurrentPage() on a non-object
```

I have confirmed that the code `$query = Product::find(1)->options()` returns a collection of options. The `$query` object seems to be of type `hasMany`. Below are the model classes I am using.

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function options ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductOption', 'product_id');
    }
}

class ProductOption extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'product_options';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Does eloquent not return paginated results for relationships?

Comment: You could change the problem you're trying to solve. You could have 3 model objects: Product (1), ProductOptionInstance (2), ProductOption (3). You could have (2) have a 1-to-1 relationship with (1) and (3). With this idea, you'll be able to paginate on (2). From what I've understood, this could solve your issue. You can still get all the options of a product and all the product of an option easily. You could use scope features of Eloquent, for eaxample. As for the original question, idk how to get Eloquent to paginate on relationships.

Comment: Show your whole code and stack trace. Pagination works, and it seems that you are just trying to do something you should be.

Answer (score 17):

You can not lazy load relational pagination like that, instead in your Product Model put the following function below your options has many relationship

```
public function getOptionsPaginatedAttribute()
{
    return $this->options()->paginate(10);
}
```

This will allow you to call the pagination on your relational data by

```
$product->options_paginated
```

Comment: @41eight.how to pagniate ProductOption  data

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom length-aware paginator.

```
$options = new LengthAwarePaginator(Product::find(1)->options()->
            ->skip(($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 10)->take(10)->get(),
            Product::find(1)->options()->count(), 
            10, $request->input('page', 1),
            [
                // paginator options here
            ]);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$query = Product::find(1)->get()->options()->paginate();
```

Try adding get