# Paginate a relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Im trying to find a user and paginate their posts, I've tried:

```
User::find($id)->posts()->paginate();
```

This paginates the posts, but I lose the users information. I also need to get the users information out along with their posts.

How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497604/laravel-eloquent-pagination-on-relationships

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by passing a function when eager loading:

```
User::find($id)->with(['posts' => function($query) use ($limit) {
    $query->paginate($limit);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Close, but this returns a collection of posts and not a LengthAwarePaginator

Answer (score -1):

**Just inverse it**

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id',$user_id)->with('user')->paginate();
```

**Access user**

```
foreach ($posts as $post){
    $post->user;
}
```

Comment: This just gets the posts though - I still need the user data as a collection.

Comment: Still no good im afraid, I just want one User collection and paginate the related posts from this.

Comment: Show the way you access user from post

Comment: I don't want to access user from posts, I want to get the user and access posts as a relation of user.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this but I believe it could work something like this

```php
$user = User::find($id)
```

Send that to the view and then you can access the User as

```php
{{ $user->property }}
```

and for his posts

```php
@foreach ($user->posts()->paginate(15) as $post)
    // do something
@endforeach
{{ $user->posts()->links() }}
```

**UPDATE**
However this is not the best practice.
You could also send both $user and $user->posts()->paginate() to the view.

Comment: Should keep logic out of views.

Comment: I know it is not the best practice.