# Laravel pagination to Has Many relationship in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, pagination, has-many, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have two models

**Album**

```
public function AlbumImage(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\AlbumGallery');
    }
```

**AlbumGallery**

In controller i have following code

```
  $data=  Album::where('id', $id)->with('AlbumImage')->first();
```

Now i need to paginate only album gallery .I have tried following methods but it doesnt work

```
   $data=  Album::where('id', $id)->with('AlbumImage')->first()->paginate(2);
```

Also tried this question answer
[Laravel Eloquent pagination on relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497604/laravel-eloquent-pagination-on-relationships)

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: laravel 5.4 i am using

Comment: describe not working.

Comment: @davejal.sorry i didnt got what you said

Comment: describe what you mean with not working

Answer (score 0):

So giving respect to [your mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497604/laravel-eloquent-pagination-on-relationships), add to your `Album` model:

```
public function getAlbumImagePaginatedAttribute()
{
    return $this->AlbumImage()->paginate(3);
}
```

And use it in blade view files like this:

```
{{ $album->name }}<br>

<ul>
@foreach($album->album_image_paginated as $album_gallery)
    <li>{{ $album_gallery->gallery_name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>

{{ $album->album_image_paginated->links() }}
```

And for API calls you may use something like this:

```
Route::get('/albums/{id}', function($id) {

   $album = \App\Album::findOrFail($id);

   return [
       'id' => $album->id,
       'images' => $album->album_image_paginated,
   ];
});
```

So the response will be :

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "images":{  
      "total":6,
      "per_page":3,
      "current_page":1,
      "last_page":2,
      "next_page_url":"http://example.app/api/albums/1?page=2",
      "prev_page_url":null,
      "from":1,
      "to":3,
      "data":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "gallery_name":"first image",
            "album_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-02-22 09:47:46",
            "updated_at":"2017-02-22 09:47:46"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "gallery_name":"Second",
            "album_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-02-22 09:48:31",
            "updated_at":"2017-02-22 09:48:31"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "gallery_name":"33",
            "album_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-02-22 09:48:35",
            "updated_at":"2017-02-22 09:48:35"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Peter .thanks i have tried in this i am facing problem is if i click on pagniation link it wont chage album images .\

Comment: @iCoders Ok, also make sure when clicking to link, that url actually changes to `http://example.app/api/albums/1?page=2`, so it has `page=2`. also in case you have several entities that should be paginaed, may be need to set custom `pageGallery` parameter so that paginator understands it

Comment: @Peter.Thanks.yapage url isd changing  already only thing is to change gallery